# Check if record was just destroyed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So there is

```
record.new_record?
```

To check if something is new

I need to check if something is on it's way out.

```
record = some_magic
record.destroy
record.is_destroyed? # => true
```

Something like that. I know destroying freezes the object, so frozen? sort of works, but is there something explicitly for this task?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Just do it:

```
record.destroyed?
```

Details are here [ActiveRecord::Persistence](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html)

Comment: In OP's question case, this is the best. However, if the DB-record has disappeared without interacting Ruby variable `record`, `destroyed?` still returns `false`, because the method does not look up the DB. So, @ryanb's answer of using `YourModel.exists?` is more reliable.

Answer (score 60):

You can do this.

```
Record.exists?(record.id)
```

However that will do a hit on the database which isn't always necessary. The only other solution I know is to do a callback as theIV mentioned.

```
attr_accessor :destroyed
after_destroy :mark_as_destroyed
def mark_as_destroyed
  self.destroyed = true
end
```

And then check `record.destroyed`.

Comment: I think some context is helpful here.  It depends on why you want to know if an object has been destroyed.  If you're doing it as part of a unit test, then the extra hit against the database is fine.  If you're doing it as part of the app, then going the second route might be a better bet.

Comment: This is no longer necessary, use `object.destroyed?`

Comment: in Rails 4, `DEPRECATION WARNING: You are passing an instance of ActiveRecord::Base to `exists?`. Please pass the id of the object by calling `.id`.`

Comment: Still need `Record.exists?` in controller specs, because I can't reload destroyed record to check if it is `destroyed?`. But if I have instance variable to check with `assings`, then I can use `destroyed?`.

Comment: @Daniel Huckstep, if you are still alive, please, change the accepted answer for the correct one!

Comment: Note that if you have assigned nested attributes before calling `save`, and want to check if an association **will** be destroyed, you can use the `object.marked_for_destruction?` method too. This method is also handy if you set `autosave: true` on your association. See: https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation/marked_for_destruction%3F

Comment: `object.destroyed?` is great unless you are testing cascades. It will be incorrect for those. If you call `object.reload`, you'll get `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. I think Ryan's original suggestion of `Record.exists?(record)` is best.

Answer (score 11):

This is coming very soon. In the latest [Riding Rails](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/8/13/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-the-bugmash-edition) post, it says this:

> And finally, it's not necessarily
>   BugMash-related, but José Valim -
>   among dozens of other commits - added
>   model.destroyed?. This nifty method
>   will return true only if the instance
>   you're currently looking at has been
>   successfully destroyed.

So there you go. Coming soon!

Answer (score 6):

`destroy`ing an object doesn't return anything other than a call to `freeze` (as far as I know) so I think `frozen?` is your best bet. Your other option is to rescue from `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if you did something like `record.reload`.

I think Mike's tactic above could be best, or you could write a wrapper for these cases mentioned if you want to start 'making assumptions'.

Cheers.

Comment: I currently just check frozen?, but really I can load something and freeze it for some other purpose, and it would be a lie then...

In the current situation, frozen? works fine, but I don't want to rely on it long term.

Answer (score 6):

While record.destroyed? works fine, and does return true or false, you can also DRY this up a little bit and create the if condition on the line you call destroy on in your controller.

```
record = Object.find(params[:id])
if record.destroy
  ... happy path
else
  ... sad path
end
```

Realize this post is a bit late in the game. But should anyone want to discuss this more, i'm game! 
Side note: I also had an after_destroy validation on my model and while it worked, a separate method for something like this seems like overkill ;)

Comment: This does not work!  `record.destroy` will always return `record.freeze`, a frozen instance of the record right before it was deleted -- so even `record.destroy.destroyed?` wouldn't work!

Comment: Check out the documentation for `destroy`: https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Persistence/destroy

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more of the logic of your app, I think that frozen? is your best bet.

Failing that, you could certainly add a "destroyed" attribute to your models that you trigger in the callbacks and that could be checked against if you want a more precise solution.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

```
  record.destroyed? # doesn't always work (see below)
  # or...
  Record.exists?(record.id) # very fast!
```

You'd think that `record.destroyed?` is better because it doesn't send an extra database request but actually `Record.exists?` is *so extremely* fast, that this typically isn't a reason to prefer one over the other.

Don't use the return value of `record.destroy`, which will *always* return a frozen instance of the record, whether it's deleted or not, from right before you tried to deleted it.  See here: https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Persistence/destroy

```rb
# Assuming no issues when destroying the record...
x = record_one.destroy
x.destroyed? # Would return false! (even though the record no longer exists in the db)
Record.exists?(x) # Would correctly return false
# vs.
record_two.destroy
record_two.destroyed? # Would correctly return true
Record.exists?(record_two) # Would correctly return false
```

If you're in a controller, `destroy!` will throw a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed`, which you can catch, based on `before_destroy` callbacks.

```rb
def destroy
  render json: @record.destroy!
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed
  # @record will work fine down here, it still exists.
  render json: { errors: ["Record not destroyed"] }
end
```